# SQL Joins not working correctly when no data present

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I've got the following code, where I build a tag from an entity

```
entityManager.createQuery("SELECT new com.myproject.rs.platform.models.dto.TagViewDto" +
    "(t.id, t.name, t.description, count(DISTINCT qa.id) , count(DISTINCT qd.id), count(DISTINCT qw.id)) FROM Tag t " +
    "LEFT JOIN t.questions qa LEFT JOIN t.questions qd LEFT JOIN t.questions qw " +
    "WHERE qd.persistDateTime < :now and :oneDay < qd.persistDateTime " +
    "and qw.persistDateTime < :now and :oneWeek < qw.persistDateTime " +
    "GROUP BY t " +
    "ORDER BY t.persistDateTime DESC", TagViewDto.class)
        .setParameter("oneDay", localDateTime.minusHours(24))
        .setParameter("now", localDateTime)
        .setParameter("oneWeek", localDateTime.minusDays(7))
        .setFirstResult((curPageNumber - 1) * itemsOnPage).setMaxResults(itemsOnPage)
        .getResultList();
```

Each tag has an id, name, description and how many questions it has, how many it has in a day, and how many it has in a week.

The problem is, I can't seem to display tags that have no questions tied to them, and also if a tag doesn't have any daily or weekly question, the tag itself is also not displayed.
I tried writing a coalesce() in the constructor itself, with the arguments of count and then 0, but it does not seem to work, and coalesce returns an int instead of a long.

How would I make tags with no questions or with no recent(in a day's or week's time) questions still get displayed? Preferably with these null values being replaced with a 0

EDIT: Here are some example datasets

```
tag:
  - id: 1
    name: "one"
    description: "javascript"
    persist_date: 2021-10-29 14:04:39

  - id: 2
    name: "two"
    description: "java"
    persist_date: 2017-03-12 00:00:00

  - id: 3 
    name: "three"
    description: "c"
    persist_date: 2023-08-29 00:00:00

  - id: 4
    name: "four"
    description: "cpp"
    persist_date: 2020-21-29 00:00:00

  - id: 5
    name: "five"
    description: "python"
    persist_date: 2021-06-20 00:00:00

  - id: 6
    name: "six"
    description: "go"
    persist_date: 2021-04-29 00:00:00
question:
  - id: 1 #current
    title: "one"
    description: "javascript"
    persist_date: 2022-01-31 12:00:00

  - id: 2 #current
    title: "two"
    description: "java"
    persist_date: 2022-01-31 12:00:00

  - id: 3  #current    
    title: "three"
    description: "c"
    persist_date: 2022-01-31 12:00:00

  - id: 4 #threeDaysAgo
    title: "four"
    description: "cpp"
    persist_date: 2022-01-28 12:00:00

  - id: 5 #TwoDaysAgo
    title: "five"
    description: "python"
    persist_date: 2022-01-29 12:00:00

  - id: 6 #weekAndADayAgo
    title: "six"
    description: "go"
    persist_date: 2022-01-23 12:00:00
questionHasTag:
  - tag_id: 1
    question_id: 6

  - tag_id: 1
    question_id: 5    

  - tag_id: 1
    question_id: 4

  - tag_id: 3
    question_id: 6

  - tag_id: 3
    question_id: 2

  - tag_id: 3
    question_id: 1

  - tag_id: 4
    question_id: 6

  - tag_id: 2
    question_id: 2

  - tag_id: 2
    question_id: 6
```

and the expected tag json:

```
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "one",
      "description": "javascript ",
      "questionCount": 3,
      "questionCountOneDay": 0,
      "questionCountOneWeek": 2
    }
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "two",
      "description": "java ",
      "questionCount": 2,
      "questionCountOneDay": 1,
      "questionCountOneWeek": 1
    }
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "three",
      "description": "c ",
      "questionCount": 3,
      "questionCountOneDay": 2,
      "questionCountOneWeek": 2
    }
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "four",
      "description": "cpp ",
      "questionCount": 1,
      "questionCountOneDay": 0,
      "questionCountOneWeek": 0
    }
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "five",
      "description": "python ",
      "questionCount": 0,
      "questionCountOneDay": 0,
      "questionCountOneWeek": 0
    }
    {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "six",
      "description": "go ",
      "questionCount": 0,
      "questionCountOneDay": 0,
      "questionCountOneWeek": 0
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using `LEFT JOIN` instead?

Comment: By the way, a tip: [text blocks](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/378) makes embedding SQL easier.

Comment: By having your JOIN conditions in a WHERE clause instead of an ON clause in your join statement, you are excluding and Tags that don't meet that where clause (aka: that don't have questions).

Comment: Please provide a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: @TheImpaler I have provided some datasets and the expected json, sorry for the wait

Comment: @JohnGlenn that seems to work but weirdly. Tags that, for example, have 7 questions with a persist date of 2021-01-31 and 3 questions with 2022-01-31, display their daily question count still as 10. The weekly count seems to be fine, yet sometimes it still displays questions incorrectly, although for the most part it works

Comment: @AndreiGaina - Your joins should also include the tag ID, right? Without it, your question counts won't be restricted to questions from that tag.

Comment: @JohnGlenn Restriction works fine, I probably phrased it wrong. Say a tag has 4 questions, two submitted a year ago, two submitted just now. It'll still show the questionCountOneDay still as 4, while the questionCountOneWeek works just fine, showing only 2. As it is now, there is no problem with which question belongs to which tag

Comment: What about this:
```SELECT new com.myproject.rs.platform.models.dto.TagViewDto(
 t.id, t.name, t.description,
 ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t.questions qa ),
 ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t.questions qd WHERE qd.persistDateTime BETWEEN :oneDay AND :now ),
 ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t.questions qw WHERE qw.persistDateTime BETWEEN :oneWeek AND :now )
FROM Tag t```

Comment: @JohnGlenn Thank you for the answer, but apparently the issue was more stupid than I thought)
The ON clauses should've been placed right after the joins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who stumbled on this question and is looking for an answer, you should use ON clause instead of WHERE, and also the ON clauses should be right after the LEFT JOINS:

```
"LEFT JOIN t.questions qa " +
"LEFT JOIN t.questions qd ON qd.persistDateTime < :now and :oneDay < qd.persistDateTime " + 
"LEFT JOIN t.questions qw ON qw.persistDateTime < :now and :oneWeek < qw.persistDateTime"
```